# Filter datagridview using datetimepicker?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing an application where there will be two filters.

First filter is when user will enter an `ID` then only the data of that `ID` is displayed. I've managed to done that but the problem is on the second filter I try to implement. After the user enter the ID then display the ID data, then the user can filter that data even more based dates. So I try using `datetimepicker` tools.

But when I choose the date, `mydatagridview` won't filter to show only the chosen date data. It still shows all the data from the first ID filter.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Here is my code :

```
private void trackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        if (dataGridView1.Visible == true)
        {
            webBrowser1.Location = new Point(12, 397);
        }
        //DataTable dt = null;
        string connoInput = textBox1.Text;
        string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.BMSDATAConnectionString;
        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TrackCon\TrackCon\BMSDATA.sdf;Persist Security Info = True;Password=Gdex123$"))
        {

                string Ids = "conno= '" + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text.Trim(), @"\s*\n\s*", "' OR conno= '") + "'";
                SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT conno,cmpsno,ctrx,dsysdate,cstnno,corigin FROM BRDATA WHERE " +Ids, con);
                SqlCeDataAdapter adap = new SqlCeDataAdapter(com);
                DataSet set = new DataSet();
                adap.Fill(set);
                if (set.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    bRDATABindingSource1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];
                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bRDATABindingSource1;
                con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void trackMPSbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        if (dataGridView1.Visible == true)
        {
            webBrowser1.Location = new Point(12, 397);
        }
        //DataTable dt = null;
        //string connoInput = textBox1.Text;
        string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.BMSDATAConnectionString;
        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TrackCon\TrackCon\BMSDATA.sdf;Persist Security Info = True;Password=Gdex123$"))
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bRDATABindingSource1;
            string Ids = "cmpsno= '" + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(textBox2.Text.Trim(), @"\s*\n\s*", "' OR cmpsno= '") + "'";
            con.Open();
            SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT conno,cmpsno,ctrx,dsysdate,cstnno,corigin FROM BRDATA WHERE " + Ids, con);
            SqlCeDataAdapter adap = new SqlCeDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet set = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(set);
            if (set.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                bRDATABindingSource1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bRDATABindingSource1;
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
       bRDATABindingSource1.Filter = string.Format("dsysdate = #{0}#", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString());

    }
}
```

}

*EDITED*

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning. its in WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the `DataSource` of `dataGridView1` is local variable `dt` in both your events. But you're likely trying to filter an instance field `bRDATABindingSource1`. There is no more context information for me. Are you sure this is correct?

Try to use `bRDATABindingSource1` instead of `dt`, and see if that works.

Comment: I believe your analysis is correct. If the data source of dataGridView1 were set to bRDATABindingSource1 and not changed in code, and the changes to the datasource were made to bRDATABindingSource1 instead of to the local variable, this code would probably work as expected.

Comment: I have changed the code to

dataGridview1.DataSource = bRDATABindingSource1;
 
but then it won't display any data in the gridview. Eventhough I already set the data source for my gridview in design view and also in my code to bRDATABindingSource1.

Comment: @shahrul1509 I guess you hasn't set your `bRDATABindingSource1`. Try `bRDATABindingSource1.DataSource = set.DataTables[0];` and then `dataGridView1.DataSource = bRDATABindingSource1;`. Of course there is more elegant approach, but you should find out if that is the issue in the first place.

Comment: Done it and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot @Kirin Yao. But mine is a little different : 

bRDATABindingSource1.DataSource = set.Tables[0];

Comment: Yeah, it should be `Tables[0]`. It's a typo:)

Comment: :D
but @KirinYao, it works perfectly but now there is one more problem. The datetimepicker works fine. But when I filter the datagrid using the date, then I want to enter new ID to display new data, it isn't working. Every time I enter new ID then want to display the ID data, it won't show any data.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the code like now. You could edit your question and paste your current code. Or, you can add break points, and debug it first.

Comment: I've already edited the code. I've found the problem. It's not that it doesn't display anything at all. It doesn't display anything because the date filter is still running. Hence, when I enter new ID, if the ID doesn't match any date that I had previously chose, then it won't display anything at all. Is there any way to reset the date filter when I want to enter new IDs?

Comment: Try `bRDATABindingSource1.Filter = null` before you set it to `dataGridView1.DataSource`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KirinYao!!It works perfectly. One more thing, do you have links on how to set the datetimepicker string format expression??because mine can only filter data which have dates only. Most of my data is a datetime, hence it cannot detect those data that contain datetime.